# Jenkins script not running - stalled/stuck?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run a python script on Jenkins - I already tried it in jupyter and it works fine there.

When I try running it in Jenkins, I don't get any error message unfortunately, I get an infinite wheel rotating.

The console output circle at the top is gray, and I get the following circling wheel:
[image]

Since I don't see any error message - I am not really sure where to start. I don't think it is a matter of being more patient since it takes ~5 minutes to run it all in Jupyter, but left it running overnight in Jenkins and the script still hadn't finished the next day. It isn't an authorization error, since I've had those before and I get an error message on what to fix.

In case this is relevant - the progress bar seems to be almost done, but in red:
[image]

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?